# Expand C# object to override property name in XML documentation

Tags: c#, xml, api, documentation

I'm currently building and endpoint (lets call it myendpoint) and would like to be able to manipulate the parameter names to match requirements. Lets say that I have an object called `myobject` that contains the following properties `name`, `address`, `addressCity`, and `addressState`. However, I need `addressCity` and `addressState` to show up in the documentation as `address-city` and `address-state`. Is there a way to override the names of the properties inside the object to accomplish this?

```
public class myobject
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public string address { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("address-city")]
    public string addressCity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("address-state")]
    public string addressState { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets some information
/// </summary>
/// <param name="myobject"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public IHttpActionResult GetInformation([FromURI] Object myobject)
{
   // Code
}
```

Current documentation on the help page shows up as:
http://localhost:9999/api/myendpoint?name={name}&address={address}&addressCity={addressCity}&addressState={addressState}

I would like it to show up as:
http://localhost:9999/api/myendpoint?name={name}&address={address}&address-city={address-city}&address-state={address-state}

I have tried to use multiple attributes such as `DisplayName`, `JsonProperty` (currently using this but the XML documentation does not pickup on the new name).

Edit: Added function

Comment: Where is the reference to the mentioned variables in the added function?

Comment: I'm sorry what are you asking for?

Comment: You mention in your description a.o. address-state and addressState but in your code snippet none of these words are present,at least I don't see them. These are apparently part of `myobject` but I don't see any documentation about it.

Comment: @albert I mentioned that they are apart of myobject, but I just wrote the class out as an edit.